# Extracting XML (as xml type) using xpath query in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to extract a chunk of XML (ie the whole xml of a node, not just content) using an xpath query in SQL. I can extract a single content field but am not sure how to do the above.

Say the xml is as follows

> ```
> <head>
>     <instance>
>         <tag1>
>               <tag2>data</tag2>
>               <tag3>data</tag3> 
>         </tag1> 
>     </instance> 
> </head>
> ```

I would like to extract all of the xml inside tag1, and was hoping something like this would work in a SQL query:

```
Table.value('(/head/instance/tag1)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as "col"
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: @user270370: This is not asking for an XPath expression but for no standar SQL type conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
Select Cast(Table.xmlcolumnname.query('/head/instance/tag1') as varchar(max)) 'col';
```

(its not checked! may contain typo..)